# How to do it in Grails , I am using Grais 3.2.11?

Tags: grails

I have a User domain and several other domains having userId .

How can I clear them all while deleting user? Without manually finding it one by one in other domains and removing it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have defined the right `cascade` and ownerships for your domain classes and then grails will do this for you.

I think the entry in official documentation about cascade describes your issue exactly, check it: http://docs.grails.org/3.2.1/ref/Database%20Mapping/cascade.html

Comment: I am not using any relationship , userId in my case is a field (Long userId).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without full reference(so it should be instead of `Long userId` be `User user` that delete it)
But if you are looking for a hack, so you can get all domains and filter they by field userId, then find all by current userId and remove they.
Take a look on `grailsDomainClassMappingContext, PersistentEntity, PersistentProperty`